# Can't get Spring @CacheEvict to work

Tags: java, spring, caching, annotations

I'm trying to use Spring Cacheable

```
public interface UnStandardizedValueRepository extends CrudRepository<UnStandardizedValue, Integer> {
@Cacheable(value = "rest_respond_values", unless="#result == null")
UnStandardizedValue findByValue(String value);
@Override
@CacheEvict(value = "rest_respond_values", condition="#unValue != null")
<S extends UnStandardizedValue> S save(S unValue);
}
```

And all the tries to evict the value when i do "save" hasn't worked. If I do it manually (get cachemanager and evict) it works, but not the annotation way.

```
UnStandardizedValue test = repository.findByValue("x 99");
Assert.assertNotNull(test);
test.setValue("y");
repository.save(test);
//cacheManager.getCache("rest_respond_values").evict("x 99"); //works!
test = null; //just for safety
test = repository.findByValue("x 99"); //gets "y"
Assert.assertNull(test); //expected null but was "y"
```

It seems like the object I change is the same as the one in the Cache. But when I do "save" it should have been evicted, and not been returned by that "x 99"

I've tried to change:

```
    @Override
    @CacheEvict(value = "rest_respond_values", condition="#unValue != null")
    <S extends UnStandardizedValue> S save(S unValue);

    @Override
    @CacheEvict(value = "rest_respond_values", key="#unValue.value", condition="#unValue != null")
    <S extends UnStandardizedValue> S save(S unValue);
```

I even tested allEntries = true, but no luck. Any suggestions?

UnStandardizedValue has id (Integer) and value (String) with getters and setters. And toString returns value.

So the Cacheable works, but not the eviction (unless done manually).

Anyone knows how to fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I have equals and hashcode in UnStandardizedValue class.

I made an empty method with the exact same eviction as the "save" (see code below) and it works (both before or after the save command) and I use the same object in save as in testEvict.

```
public interface UnStandardizedValueRepository extends CrudRepository<UnStandardizedValue, Integer> {
    @Cacheable(value = "rest_respond_values", key = "#p0", unless="#result == null")
    UnStandardizedValue findByValue(String value);

//does not evict
    @Override
    @CacheEvict(value = "rest_respond_values", key="#p0.value", condition="#unValue != null")
    <S extends UnStandardizedValue> S save(S unValue);

//evicts
    @CacheEvict(value = "rest_respond_values", key="#p0.value", condition="#unValue != null")
    default void testEvict(UnStandardizedValue unValue) {

    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
A real interesting part is that the eviction fails for "allEntries = true"

```
@CacheEvict(value = "rest_respond_values", condition="#unValue != null", allEntries = true)
    <S extends UnStandardizedValue> S save(S unValue);
```

But the same annotation works for testEvict-method.

```
@CacheEvict(value = "rest_respond_values", condition="#unValue != null", allEntries = true)
    default void testEvict(UnStandardizedValue unValue) {

    }
```

So it feels like there's something fishy about the save-method.

Comment: The key you use for caching and eviction should match. By default it uses the method arguments as key and return value as value for caching. To use eviction the key should match, so you should use (indeed) a specific `key` attribute to point to the exact value. Also make sure that the key used for caching is actually having a correct `hashcode` and `equals` implementation. `String` should have one but is this your actual code or modified code?

Comment: this is my actual code, I added hashCode and equals but no change. I tried the same eviction on a different method (see code update) and that one works, but not on the save method.

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, you cannot use the argument's name in SPEL for repository interfaces (I don't know the reason TBH). The only way to do that I found is by using `#pX` where `X` is the number of argument. So in the above case:

```
@Override
@CacheEvict(value = "rest_respond_values", condition="#p0 != null")
<S extends UnStandardizedValue> S save(S unValue);
```